# flask abort() inside try block behaviour

Tags: python, flask

When i want to use the flask abort inside a try block i end up in my exception block

```
@app.route('/newsletters/<int:newsletter_id>', methods=['GET'])
def route_get_newsletter(newsletter_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':        
        try:
            newsletter = get_newsletter(newsletter_id)                
            if not newsletter:
               abort(404)
        except Exception, ex:
            logging.exception("Something awful happened!")
            abort(500)
        else:            
            return jsonify(newsletter=newsletter)
```

gives output:

```
ERROR:root:Something awful happened!
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "natuurpuntapi.py", line 210, in route_get_newsletter
   abort(404)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 525, in __call__
   raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs)
NotFound: 404: Not Found
```

and werkzeug NotFound is called and i get the 500 response

when i put the abort(404) outside the try: block, it works and i get the 404 response

- edit

i found that flask abort() uses the werkzeug abort() which is a class called Aborter()
when this is called it raises "raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs)"

does this mean i can not call abort inside my own try block because it will raise an exception and ends up in my exception?

Comment: can you share the code for get_newsletter(newsletter_id) function ? How do you handle exception within that function ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**`flask.abort(...)` raises itself an exception**, one of the exceptions described in the [docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/exceptions/), all subclasses of `werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException`. This is the reason why your code doesn't work.

But here is some other trivia:

- If your code raises other kinds of exceptions, Flask will automatically return a 500.
- you can create custom error handlers for HTTP status codes and exceptions: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers
- If you have `methods=['GET']`, you don't need to check for the method inside the view.

Given that knowledge we can rewrite your code like:

```
@app.route('/newsletters/<int:newsletter_id>', methods=['GET'])
def route_get_newsletter(newsletter_id):
    newsletter = get_newsletter(newsletter_id)
    return jsonify(newsletter=newsletter)

@app.errorhandler(500)
def catch_server_errors(e):
    logging.exception("Something awful happened!")
```

Comment: Markus, Your solutions works. But why does the raise fixes the problem.

Comment: I rewrote my answer. Is this better?

Comment: it must have been the heat :) - it get it now

Answer (score 8):

You can check if the error came from an HTTPException then access the .code attribute.

```py
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

@app.route('/newsletters/<int:newsletter_id>')
def route_get_newsletter(newsletter_id):
    try:
        newsletter = get_newsletter(newsletter_id)                
        if not newsletter:
            abort(404)
    except Exception as e:
        if isinstance(e, HTTPException):
            abort(e.code)
        else:
            abort(500)
    return jsonify(newsletter=newsletter)
```

Comment: It's 2021 and this is a more elegant solution 

Comment: if you are using message with abort like abort(404, "user not found"), then you could use `abort(e.code, e.data["message"])` instead of `abort(e.code)`in line number 11. Note: this will raise error if you are not populating the custom message in first go.